# Text not visible in trailing of gridtilebar in gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

Iam developing an ecommerce app with the items to add and remove button below the product image in gridview. Inbetween the button, i have a text widget to show the number of items for add and remove.The problem is the text widget is not displaying inbetwen.

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 10),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: Text(
                        '${item == null ? 0 : item}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zwqg.jpg)

Comment: please provide your gridview code.

Answer (score 0):

by default, gridview children has same size for all children based on aspectratio.

Solution:

opsi 1:  Fitted box will scaled down your widget child size.

```
Gridview.count(
....
children:[
  FittedBox(
    child: // your widget her
```

opsi 2: set `childAspectRatio:` to your gridview,

```
GridView.count(
   //var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   // double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
   // double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
   // this value that i usually use in mobile, idk for web size. you can try by your self
   childAspectRatio: itemHeight / itemWidth,
   children: []
```

this will customize your grid space